# Does tensorflow gpu version uses cudnn by default

Tags: tensorflow, cudnn

as the title, I have installed tensorflow gpu version and I want to know whether tensorflow-gpu uses CUDNN by default!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorflow Release 1.6.0 Prebuilt binaries are now built against CUDA 9.0 and cuDNN 7.